# apa6 or biblatex-apa6 error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: biblatex, apa6

I am requested to use the `apa6` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/apa6?lang=en) but cannot compile the examples provided there in the `sample/` folder (by running `pdflatex shortsample.tex`, for example), and instead I get the error ''`Missing \begin{document}`'' within file `apa6.cbx` provided by the `biblatex-apa6` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa6?lang=en).

At the end of this question I paste the relevant excerpt of the log file. Below follows additional information.

In the manual `apa6.pdf` there is no obvious instruction on how to install the package, but in the root folder a `.dtx` and an `.ins` file are provided and after googling I found that compiling the `.ins` file (e.g., `pdflatex apa6.ins`) generates a set of files including the `apa6.cls` file.

After copying the `apa6.cls` file to the `samples/` folder and running `pdflatex shortsample.tex` I got an error about `biblatex` and `apa6` style. I found online the package `biblatex-apa6`, and in the instructions in file `biblatex-apa6.pdf`, section 3, it says that it can be installed by copying `.cbx`, `.bbx` and `.lbx` files to subfolders of `<texmf>/tex/latex/biblatex/`. In my computer `biblatex` (installed with the package `texlive-bibtex-extra)` the relevant `<texmf>` is `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/`. I copied the files, ran `texhash` and I now get mentioned error.

### Excerpt of `shortsample.log`:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'apa6'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'apa6.cbx' found.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/apa6.cbx
File: apa6.cbx 2020/05/03 v8.4 APA 6th ed. biblatex citation style
Package biblatex Info: Delimiter 'nameyeardelim' in context '' already
defined,
 overwriting.
Package biblatex Info: Delimiter 'nameyeardelim' in context 'textcite'
already
defined, overwriting.
Package biblatex Info: Delimiter 'andothersdelim' in context '' already
defined
, overwriting.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\fullcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\citeauthor'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\citeyear'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.509 ...DelimAlias*[nptextcite]{finalnamedelim}[parencite]{finalnamedelim}
```

Comment: `[p arencite]` has a space. Is that incorrect?

Comment: apa6 is a class: from the manual (section 3.1) `\documentclass[options]{apa6}`. What code did you run to produce the errors? Are you compiling with pdflatex engine, or xelatex/lualatex?

Comment: Only a small example code is needed, which can compile and reproduce the error.

Comment: It would really help if you could share (and run) a short example document, so we all know what we are talking about. (That is usually called an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. It need not contain more than `\documentclass` a few preamble lines and "lorem ipsum" as well as a citation in the document body.) In this case I have a hunch this could be a version problem, so the full `.log` file would be nice as well. If it is too long for the question, please upload it to a text-sharing site such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/

Comment: For now my working hypothesis is as follows. You installed your TeX live system via your Linux distribution (amongst other things also `sudo apt install texlive-bibtex-extra`). The TeX live versions shipped by Linux distributions can be quite outdated and in general don't keep up-to-date with CTAN. Then you installed the current version of `biblatex-apa6` from CTAN. That version is intended to be used with a more modern version of `biblatex` than the `biblatex` shipped by your Linux distribution. That version mismatch causes the error.

Comment: There is no simple way out of this with your current setup. That's one of the reasons why it is generally discouraged to install packages manually from CTAN. Generally it is much better to install all packages through the same system (in your case your Linux distribution). But if your Linux is stuck with an old TeX live that doesn't have `apa6` or `biblatex-apa6` that is an issue. Do double check, though, if (an older version of) `apa6` is available via `apt`, that version would presumably load an old version of `biblatex-apa` (which again should be available) instead of `biblatex-apa6`.

Comment: The radical way to get a more up-to-date system with `apa6` and `biblatex-apa6` would be to remove the TeX live installed via `apt`/`apt-get` and get a vanilla TeX live from TUG instead (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864).

Comment: Reply to Cicada: the space in [p arencite] was a leftover from copy-paste with a line break. I fixed it. I used pdflatex. I tried luatex too but that would give a different error. Anything that starts with `\documentclass[man, 12pt, a4paper]{apa6}` and has later in the preamble `\usepackage[style=apa6,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}` yields the problem.

Comment: Reply to moewe: Your working hypothesis is correct and indeed the installed version of biblatex has an `apa` style, but the journal is requesting class `apa6`. I checked the link you provided for the TUG installation and it seems quite involved.

Comment: There is a difference here between the *class* `apa6` and the bibliography style `biblatex-apa6` (or in older versions `biblatex-apa`). It is possible that the class `apa6` is available on your system in one of then many `texlive-...` packages served via `apt`. That version is likely to be compatible with all other packages on your system. So I suggest you completely remove the class `apa6` and bibliography style `biblatex-apa6` you manually installed. Instead make sure you have `texlive-publishers` and `texlive-bibtex-extra` installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost always a problematic to install LaTeX packages, document classes or bibliography styles manually from CTAN. One of the risks with that is that you can run into version incompatibilities.

Here, you are using a TeX live from the repositories of your Linux distribution. Depending on the exact version of your OS that TeX live version may be a little or really quite outdated by today's standard.

In particular the error you get suggests that the version of `biblatex` installed on your system is too old for the `biblatex-apa6` you manually installed from CTAN. (Now one might be tempted to manually update `biblatex` from CTAN, but this is a recipe for disaster due to the dependencies, so I strongly recommend you don't do that.)

I suggest you remove the files you installed manually (the class `apa6` and the `biblatex` style `biblatex-apa6`). Instead make sure that you have installed the packages

- [`texlive-publishers`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/bionic/all/texlive-publishers/filelist), which contains `apa6` and
- [`texlive-bibtex-extra`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/bionic/all/texlive-bibtex-extra/filelist), which contains `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` (which in your outdated version of TeX live is equivalent to a modern `biblatex-apa6`; the current version of `biblatex-apa` implements 7th edition APA style)

from your Linux distribution.

With those packages installed, you should be able to run documents using the `apa6` document class (using `biblatex-apa` instead of `biblatex-apa6`).

---

In case you want to have a fully up-to-date TeX live system, you should look into installing "vanilla" TeX live from TUG.org. See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864).

If you get TeX live 2020 from TUG.org, then you should install `apa6` and `biblatex-apa6` via `tlmgr`.

---

Since you mention a journal requesting you use `apa6`, double check that they also really want you to use `biblatex-apa(6)`. The `biblatex`-based workflow of `biblatex-apa` is quite different from the standard LaTeX citation workflow and generally publishers seem to prefer the old BibTeX ways. Double check with their submission guidelines. Maybe they'd prefer if you used `apacite` instead of `biblatex-apa(6)`.

Comment: I was unaware of the existence of the `texlive-publishers` package and that it had the `apa6` document class. Indeed by making `\usepackage[style=apa,...]{biblatex}` the file now compiles. Thank you!

Comment: @Joao Basically every package in TeX live is available in some `texlive-...` package from your Linux distribution provided it is old enough that is was available back when the TeX live was packaged by your distributor. The trick is to find out which package contains the files you are looking for. (I usually just google the package name and "ubuntu" and that is often enough, but if not, `apt` has a search function)